# Saber si un empleado se está pasando información del servidor a su entorno local

Tags: windows-server

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de poder auditar que archivos se "pasa" un usuario del servidor de ficheros a su entorno local, ya sea copiando, moviendo, cortando etc.

Tengo activado el visor de eventos pero solo puedo ver a que archivo a accedido el usuario o que archivo ha borrado, pero necesitamos saber si algún empleado se está transfiriendo archivos a su entorno local y que archivos son.

Por mas que he buscado no encuentro la forma y por última instancia acudo a vosotros para ver si podéis echarme una mano.

Gracias.

Comment: Esto más bien deberías preguntarlo en un sitio de gestión de sistemas, en SO se hacen preguntas sobre programación, no auditoria de sistemas. Prueba en serverfault, que seguro que te pueden ayudar mucho mejor!

Comment: Gracias Benito!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.